# To env or not to env

Tags: shell

What is the difference between the command

```
$ env FOO=bar baz
```

and

```
$ FOO=bar baz
```

What effect does `env` have?

Comment: Sort of a side question, but what is it the feature itself called when you set an environment variable for a single subcommand like that? I've always had a hard time finding info on this because I don't know what it's called.

Comment: @JohnCromartie, you should ask that as a question.

Comment: For bash, it's documented here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

Comment: @JohnCromartie It's an optional component of every shell command, so it is in the "Simple Commands" section of most shell manuals. For POSIX, that would be [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01). glenn linked the analogous section from the bash manual for you already.

Comment: Setting a variable that does not exist via an assignment creates a shell variable.  Setting it via ENV or exporting the variable pushes the variable into the shell's execution environment.  Changing the value of an existing variable will update the execution environment value if one exists, otherwise change it in the shell internal variables.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent.

The main difference is that `env FOO=bar baz` involves invoking an intermediary process between the shell and `baz`, where as with `FOO=bar baz` the shell directly invokes `baz`.
So in that regard, `FOO=bar baz` is preferred.

The only situations I find myself using `env FOO=bar` in is where I have to pass a command to another command.
As a specific example, lets say I have a wrapper script that performs some modifications of the environment, and then calls `exec` on the command that was passed to it, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
FOO=bob
some stuff
exec "$@"
```

If you execute it as `myscript FOO=bar baz`, the `exec` will throw an error as `exec FOO=bar baz` is invalid.
Instead you call it as `myscript env FOO=bar baz` which gets executed as `exec env FOO=bar baz`, and is perfectly valid.

Comment: You can do `FOO=bar exec baz` though, so you don't need `env` in your last point.

Comment: When you `exec` something, does it use your current environment?

Comment: Ditto @StephaneChazelas, and you can also `sudo FOO=bar baz` to pass environment variables without the need for `env`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas that only works if I want to put `FOO=bar` in the script. If `FOO` isn't always `bar`, I don't want to hard code it, and instead pass it in.

Comment: @glennjackman yes it does, as long as the variables are exported or passed before the `exec`, such as `FOO=bar exec baz`.

Comment: @mtmiller you're right, bad example. There are other programs which you can't do that, but they're obscure. Thought `sudo` did and it would be a good example. My mistake :-(

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your point. I thought you were saying that you can't pass env vars with `exec`.

Comment: note that in an example like this, many shells will optimize the last command in a script into an `exec` automatically if it looks reasonable to do so.

Answer (score 17):

In this particular example, there is no effective difference, assuming your shell is a POSIX-compatible shell, and assuming `baz` is an executable and not a shell builtin.

If your shell is *not* a POSIX-compatible shell, for example `csh` or `tcsh`, the syntax

```
FOO=bar baz
```

does not work, and there is no equivalent shell syntax. For those shells, the `env` command is the only way to override or inject environment variables for a single command.

If `baz` is a shell builtin, let's say `fc` for example, then `env` will not give the same results, because `env` is executing a new process instead of being run directly by the command shell. Moreover, there is no `fc` executable, it can only be run as a shell builtin because of the way it interacts with the shell environment, and so `env` will *never* work with a builtin like `fc`.

In addition, `env` offers the `-i` option, which allows you to start a command in an empty environment with only a specified set of environment variables. So `env` can be very useful for starting processes in sanitized environments, for example

```
env -i HOME=/tmp/homedir "PATH=`getconf PATH`" "TERM=$TERM" FOO=bar baz
```

Comment: When I used to use `tcsh` I would write `(setenv FOO bar; baz)` to get the equivalent function.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to what has already been said

```
VAR=value cmd args > redirs
```

being a shell (Bourne/POSIX) feature, you're limited in the name of the environment variables you pass to `cmd`. They have to be valid shell variable names and must not be read-only or special variables to the shell.

For instance, you cannot do:

```
1=foo cmd
```

Or

```
+++=bar cmd
```

`bash` doesn't allow you to do:

```
SHELLOPTS=xtrace cmd
```

While you can do:

```
env 1=foo cmd
env +++=bar cmd
env '=baz' cmd
```

(not that you want or should want to do that). Or:

```
env SHELLOPTS=xtrace cmd
```

(I sometimes need to do that).

Note that with `env` you still cannot pass an environment variable string that doesn't contain a `=` (not that you would want to do that either).

Answer (score 3):

One use of `env` is to allow `$PATH` searching of executables in shebang lines (because `env` considers the `$PATH` when searching for the executable). This is useful if the executable you want to invoke may be in different places on different machines. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

in the first line of a script with executable bit set will execute this script with Perl no matter whether it is installed in `/usr/bin/perl` or in `/usr/local/bin/perl` or in a completely different place, as long as the directory is in the path.

Of course that path search comes with an added risk, but then, the risk is not larger than if you had explicitly written `perl yourscript.pl`, which also looks up perl in the search path.

Answer (score 2):

Another time when `env` is really useful is if you want to control the environment completely.  I run a server program (Informix, in case you can't guess) whose environment I want to control completely.  I run it using `env` at the end of a script which sets a bunch of variables to the correct values:

```
env -i HOME="$IXD" \
       INFORMIXDIR="$IXD" \
       INFORMIXSERVER="$IXS" \
       ${IXC:+INFORMIXCONCSMCFG="$IXC"} \
       ${IXH:+INFORMIXSQLHOSTS="$IXH"} \
       IFX_LISTEN_TIMEOUT=3 \
       ONCONFIG="onconfig.$IXS" \
       PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:$IXD/bin" \
       SHELL=/bin/ksh \
       TZ=UTC0 \
    $ONINIT "$@"
```

The `-i` option zaps the existing environment.  The subsequent `VAR=value` options set the environment variables that I want set; the name of the program is in `$ONINIT`, and any command line arguments are passed through verbatim with `"$@"`.

The `${IXH:+INFORMIXSQLHOSTS="$IXH"}` construct only passes `INFORMIXSQLHOSTS="$IXH"` to `env` if `$IXH` is set to a non-empty value.

Answer (score 0):

[`env`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/env-invocation.html) is an executable from [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), NOT a shell builtin

```
$ type env
env is hashed (/usr/bin/env)
$ which env
/usr/bin/env
```

`$ env FOO=bar baz`:
• `bash` calls `env`, then `env` sets FOO to bar and calls `baz`

`$ FOO=bar baz`:
• `bash` sets FOO to bar and calls `baz` directly

demo of this key difference:

```
$ FOO=bar /proc/self/exe --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

```
$ env FOO=bar /proc/self/exe --version
env (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard Mlynarik, David MacKenzie, and Assaf Gordon.
```